# Finding how long a projectile is in the air: why does y=0 give the time that it lands and not the time that it is launched?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

When using the formula below to find the time the projectile is in the air, why does **y** **(vertical displacement) = 0** return the time at which the ball lands, and not the time at which the ball is released? Both occur at $y=0$.

$$ y=v_0\sin(\alpha)t+\frac12 g\,t^2 $$

- Where $v_0$ is the initial velocity, $\alpha$ is the angle of release from horizontal, $g$ is the local gravitational acceleration and $t$ is time.

An example problem is shown below
[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does both. $t=0$ is a solution to that equation just as well:

$$y=v_0\sin(\alpha) t+\frac{1}{2}gt^2\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad
0=v_0\sin(\alpha) \cdot0+\frac{1}{2}g\cdot 0^2\Leftrightarrow0=0$$

The reason that they don't find that in the solution you are showing is, that they **devide through with $t$** during their reduction. To do this, **they silently assume $t\neq 0$**.

Thereby the solution(s) they get cover all cases *except* the $t=0$ case. To complete it, this case therefore ought to be checked seperately. And by doing that (by inserting $t=0$), you'll find that $t=0$ is indeed another solution, which gives you two solutions in total.

This could be avoided by not doing the divide-through-with-$t$ step and instead just using the [usual solution formula for a quadratic equation](http://y=v_0%5Csin(%5Calpha)%20t+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7Dgt%5E2).

Comment: Thank you. The assumption when dividing through by t was what I did not understand/realise.

Answer (score 4):

The equation of the trajectory gives **both** times. It is a quadratic so it has 2 solutions for time $t$. It can be factorised into the form
$y=(a+bt)t$
so $t=0$ is one solution and $t=-a/b$ is the other.

Comment: Just to add, the reason that one of the solutions of this equation is $t=0$ is that it is derived with the assumption that the projectile is launched at $t=0$ from $y=0$.